# Array Elements Not Being Assigned Correctly in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am quite new to C++.

I am trying to write a method that reads values from the first element in each row of a two-dimensional array, determines if the element is a numeric type, and sets the element of the `numericArray` equal to 0 if it is not a numeric type, and equal to 1 if it is a numeric type.

The code works correctly in determining whether it is a numeric type or not, but does not assign the correct values to the `numericArray` elements.

As you can see, the 0, 1, and 5 elements of the `numericArray` should be 0, while the 2, 3, and 4 elements should be 1.  But that is not what I am getting.

```cpp
void DataFrame::isNumeric() {
    string str11;
    for (int aa = 0; aa < noCols ; aa ++) {
        str11 = data[0][aa];
        for (int ab = 0; ab < 1; ab++) {
            if (isdigit(str11[ab]) == 0) {
                cout << "Is digit: " << isdigit(str11[ab]) << endl;
                numericArray[ab] = 0;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Is digit: " << isdigit(str11[ab]) << endl;
                numericArray[ab] = 1;
            }
            
        } 
        
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < noCols; i++) {
        cout << "numeric[" <<i<< "] " << numericArray[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

The output I get is:

```
Is digit: 0
Is digit: 0
Is digit: 4
Is digit: 4
Is digit: 4
Is digit: 0
```

So the `numericArray` should be `[0,0,1,1,1,0]`, but am getting
`[0,-572662307,-1707333723, 41882, 14172912, 14142640]`

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  We have no idea where or what `data` comes from, or what it is, or how you are calling this function.  Also, this loop in really no loop: `for (int ab = 0; ab < 1; ab++)`.  This executes one iteration, so there is no real loop going on.

Comment: add a print for str11 after you set it...

Comment: Thank you Paul, data is a two dimensional array.  The columns are Name, Sex, Age, Height(In), Weight(lbs), and City.  The Age, Height(In), and Weight(lbs) are the only columns that contain numeric values.  Based on what I have read online (again to reiterate, I am new to C++, so its possible I don't actually know what I am talking about), but we only need to test the first character in each column to determine if it is a numeric type.  The first row in the data array is:  Alex   M   41   74  170  Singapore

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int ab = 0; ab < 1; ab++) {
```

This loop iterates exactly once, with `ab` initialized to 0. On the next iteration `ab` gets incremented exactly once, and since `ab < 1` is now false, that's it. End result: `ab` is always 0.

```
numericArray[ab] = ...
```

The shown code only initializes `numericArray[ab]`, and nothing else. As we've just discovered `ab` is always 0.

Therefore, the shown code only initializes `numericArray[0]`, after all is said and done. All other values in the `numericArray` are left as uninitialized random garbage. Perhaps both assignments should be to `numericArray[aa]` instead, but this can't be stated authoritatively; additionally, the loop's purpose is unclear, it doesn't really accomplish anything by iterating in this fashion; but in any case this is the reason for the observed results.

Comment: Ah yes!  Stupid mistake!  Should be numeric[aa] = 0.  Thank you!

Comment: @musacm35 If you didn't write the loop and instead simply did: `if (isdigit(str11[0]) == 0)` or even more explicitly: `if (!isdigit(str11.front()))`, then it makes it clear to the reader as to the code's purpose.